# Deploy demo and retail version of a .NET library via NuGet

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I need to deploy a commercial .NET library via NuGet (most likely, it will be a local source used mainly in Microsoft Visual Studio). First my potential customer installs the NuGet package with the demo version of the library for evaluation. If the customer likes it and buys it, he/she will get the retail version of the library with full functionality unlocked. Obviously, the most natural way to obtain it for the customer is to update the existing NuGet package. What is the recommended way to do this?

As I understand the NuGet infrastructure, I should play with the package versions and suffixes for them. My first try was to use suffixes '-demo' and '-retail' for the NuGet package of the same version - for example, MyLib.1.0.0-demo.nupkg and MyLib.1.0.0-retail.nupkg. But both packages were classified as pre-release versions, which would not look good for the customer. Then I tried to remove the '-retail' suffix from the retail package, and this looked better - though I don't like that the demo version is still classified as pre-release.

Maybe, there other name/version schemes for this. If so, please, recommend.

Comment: Publish a demo package on NuGet.org while setting up a private NuGet server of your own to roll out the retail package with authentication. Make sure your demo package is really for demo and contain none of the retail features (disabling them won't help as people can anyhow enable them).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the rules at https://semver.org/ - any version with a hyphen in will always be considered prerelease.

The only other thing you can use is build metadata, but that can't be used for determining precedence so isn't much good for your case.

Having the demo version be prerelease seems to make a lot of sense - it means you can release your demo and main release using the same `major.minor.patch` version, but the demo is a prerelease which means the main release always takes precedence in the ordering, so it's easy to upgrade from demo to corresponding main release.